# Marking optical or PCR duplicates with picard vs. samtools flagstat

Tags: sam, ngs, samtools, gatk, picard

I am trying to identify the best library prep method for noninvasive prenatal test samples, to be sequenced with Illumina Novaseq.

One metric that I am evaluating is the number/ percentage of PCR or optical duplicates. In order to achieve that I have done the following steps:

1. aligned the fastq reads against the reference genome with `bwa mem`
2. the `.sam` output from `bwa mem` was converted to `bam`, sorted and indexed
3. the duplicates were marked with the command `MarkDuplicates` from picard

Then if I call `samtools flagstat` on the sorted `bam` file which had the duplicates marked with picard I get:

```
26595942 + 0 in total (QC-passed reads + QC-failed reads)
0 + 0 secondary
466 + 0 supplementary
1636809 + 0 duplicates
24969064 + 0 mapped (93.88% : N/A)
26595476 + 0 paired in sequencing
13297738 + 0 read1
13297738 + 0 read2
21102678 + 0 properly paired (79.35% : N/A)
24049752 + 0 with itself and mate mapped
918846 + 0 singletons (3.45% : N/A)
462212 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr
182138 + 0 with mate mapped to a different chr (mapQ>=5)
```

Which sounds a bit strange to me, as no duplicates were found.

However, the `MarkDuplicates` command also outputted a metrics file (`dups/dupsMetrics.txt`) that did identify some duplicates. This was achieved with the following command:

```
java -jar picard.jar MarkDuplicates I=alignment/sample.sorted.bam O=alignment/sample_markDup.bam M=dups/dupsMetrics.txt
```

I see that the value under the column `PERCENT_DUPLICATION` in `dups/dupsMetrics.txt` is 0.065555 (given the column name, I would expect that the value is indeed 0.06%, and not 6.55%)

What would be the explanation between the discrepancy in the output of `samtools flagstat` and `MarkDuplicates`. Is it reasonable to expect that the value displayed by `samtools flagstat` is **rounded** to zero, given the low percentage which was observed by `MarkDuplicates` (0.06%)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are duplicates, in this line:

1636809 + 0 duplicates, gives 1636809/26595942 = 0.06154356

According to [samtools documentation for flagstat](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools-flagstat.html):

> Provides counts for each of 13 categories based primarily on bit flags
>   in the FLAG field. Each category in the output is broken down into QC
>   pass and QC fail. In the default output format, these are presented as
>   "#PASS + #FAIL" followed by a description of the category.

So you can usually take whatever is in the first column

Answer (score 2):

@StupidWolf's answer is correct -- that first number in the flagstat output is what you want to look at to see the number of reads marked as duplicates. I wanted to add that the number given in the Picard metrics file is in fact 6%, not 0.06%. This is due to an ambiguity that is widespread in Picard metrics files; in many places the program emits a fraction even when the column name is "percent of something". Soo Hee Lee wrote a very short GATK blog post about this way back in the day, see the archived version [here](https://github.com/broadinstitute/gatk-docs/blob/master/blog-2012-to-2019/2016-03-18-Metrics_say_percent_%E2%80%93_Double-check_those_decimals_%E2%80%93_Fractions_everywhere.md).

Comment: Good to know that the percentage of duplicated reads from picard and from samtools match